# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Looping with Promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm in the process of trying to create a trigger that would add up test scores and then calculate the students placement based on previous test results.

I am attempting to utilize Promises within a FOR loop as seen below:

```
exports.boxScoresUpdate = functions.database.ref('/Tests/{id}/TestScores').onWrite(event => {

    let testScr = 0;

    for (let i = 1; i <= section; i++) {
        //
        testScr += parseInt(nValue[i]);

        var index;

         admin.database().ref('TestScores').child(data.key).child('Summative').child(i).once("value").then(x => {

            xIndex = x.val();


             admin.database().ref('TestScores').child(data.key).child('Formative').child(i).once("value")
        }).then(y => { 

                yIndex = y.val();


                 admin.database().ref('StudentPlacement').child(data.key).child(xIndex + ":" + yIndex).once("value", snapshot => {

                     // SnapShot
                     console.log("Student Placement is: ", snapshot.val());

                });

        }).catch(reason => {

              // Handle Error
              console.log(reason);

        });
    }
}
```

Which I was told would not work as seen in this [post](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZIb6Uwpjc&lc=z23qujfbjwzrzd2d4acdp435mrx3k15glz2xo0uvfvpw03c010c.1502506325518576).

> "Once a promise is resolved or rejected, it forever retains that state and can't be used again. To repeat the work, I think you'd have to construct another chain of new promises representing the second iteration of work."

I have been attempting to restructure my trigger but I can not figure it out, how would I construct the new chain of promises to achieve my desired result?! Has anyone ever encountered and overcome this issue?

The behavior I am hoping to achieve is make the trigger iterate for four (4) iterations `section` is equal to 4.

I needed to utilize promises else the iteration would not complete correctly, specifically `testScr += parseInt(nValue[i]);` and the lookup for Summative and Formative.

But as stated, using Promises is working perfectly except it only iterates for the first instance, and not for when the `i = 2 or 3 or 4`

Comment: The code you shared is not a Cloud Function. I'm not really clear how you trigger this, what behavior you expect, and what behavior you actually get. Please update your question with precisely that information. You'll also want to fix the unterminated string in the innermost `once()` callback.

Comment: It's only doing one iteration because you're returning out of the whole function with `return` statement in the middle of the loop.  Putting a `return` there will not allow the loop to finish.

Comment: @DougStevenson Which return are you referring to?! Can you please provide how I should structure my code.

Comment: The `return` that's sitting right in the body of the `for` loop.  You should collect all the promises for all the work into an array, then return the promise from  `Promise.all()` to wait for everything to complete.

Comment: So I removed the `return` so the iterations continue... but I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
    at admin.database.ref.child.child.child.once.then.then.y (/user_code/index.js:175:72)` which I am not sure why!? I do not get this error if the `return` are there... but it only iterates once!?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not that clean but might help you.

```
exports.boxScoresUpdate = functions.database.ref('/Tests/{id}/TestScores').onWrite(event => {

  let testScr = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i <= section; i++) {
    //
    testScr += parseInt(nValue[i]);

    var index;

    admin.database().ref('TestScores').child(data.key).child('Summative').child(i).once("value").then(x => {
      xIndex = x.val();
      return { xIndex, index: i };
    }).then(({ xIndex, index}) => {
      admin.database().ref('TestScores').child(data.key).child('Formative').child(index).once("value").then(y => {
        yIndex = y.val();
        return { yIndex, xIndex };
      }).then(({ yIndex, xIndex}) => {
        admin.database().ref('StudentPlacement').child(data.key).child(xIndex + ":" + yIndex).once("value", snapshot => {
          console.log("Student Placement is: ", snapshot.val());
        });
      });        
    }).catch(reason => {
      console.log(reason);
    });
  }
});
```